# What kind of errors does this try-catch block handle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
//mongoose connection function

const connectDB = (url) => {
    return mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to database'))
    .catch(err=>console.log(`DB CONNECTION ERR ${err}`))
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI

//start

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB(mongoURI)
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at ${port}`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}

start()
```

This is my basic server setup. I tried messing with mongoose connection setup and app.listen() too but the catch block (in try-catch) didn't handle anything. Does the catch block only handle the errors we throw?

Comment: You already caught all errors in `.catch` method of promise inside `connectDS`, so your `await` don't throw any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try`/`catch` doesn't handle anything because you prevent it from seeing errors with this code in `connectDB`:

```
.catch(err=>console.log(`DB CONNECTION ERR ${err}`))
```

That converts rejection into fulfillment with the value `undefined` (the return value of `console.log`).

Just as you should avoid catching exceptions too early, you should avoid handling rejections too early. That's easiest (IMHO) if you consistently use `async` functions where possible:

```
const connectDB = async (url) => {          // *** Make it an `async` function
    await mongoose.connect(url, {           // *** Await connection
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log('Connected to database');   // *** Connection worked
};

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI;

//start

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB(mongoURI);          // ** Now you'll see errors here
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at ${port}`));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

start();
```

Comment: nice answer thanks, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

- "promise"(*async funcs* if you want) - throws error in `.catch()`, if not specified, it acts as usual
- "usual" - throws an error into `try{}catch(){}` block

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI;

//
//
//

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    // useFindAndModify: false,
    // useCreateIndex: true,
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log('db error', e.message);
});

//
//
//

(async()=>{
    // main code
})();

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`));
```

I refactored the code a little, it was painful to see

1. Specify local address in the "listen log", good practice, shortcut from the IDE console to browser
2. Two keys for db, I used them, maybe you will need
3. Self-executing function, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)